# IF or CASE in query (SQL Server2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a View Table, in which I have a query written like this

```
SELECT landNo, planNo, blockNo, parcelNo, RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(parcelNo))) AS parcelNoString,
    parcelAREA, '[ ' + blockNo + ' ]' + '  - ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(parcelNo))) + '  - ' +
    RTRIM(LTRIM(STR(parcelAREA))) AS DisplayName
FROM PARCELS
```

so the display name display as `[blockNo] - parcelNo - parcelArea`

Now I Have to put the check in it that if the `blockNo IS NULL` then `DisplayName`  must be as

`[] - parcelNo - parcelArea`

Can someone help in this regard.

Comment: `'[' + COALESCE(blockNo, '') + ']'`

Comment: Thanks bro that work... Please write an answer to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
'[' + COALESCE(blockNo, '') + ']'
```

coalesce returns the first non-null argument, so if blockNo is null, it'll return an empty string (`''`).

Answer (score 0):

If blockNo is a string, plain;

```
'[' + ISNULL(blockNo, '') + ']'
```

if blockNo is a numeric type, first cast it to a string or it will return `[0]`;

```
'[' + ISNULL(CAST(blockNo AS NVARCHAR), '') + ']'
```